# Cant play with friend on Minecraft PE

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So we have been able to play the game together for a few days but recently we aren't able to anymore, yes we are on the same network, yes we have the same versions, yes they are both full versions, and yes we have our servers visible, I have an ipod4 and he has an iPad, is it because i used his apple ID to download it?

Comment: Its probably not that, ive used an ipad and ipod to connect to a minecraft world and they had the same apple ID. Make sure you have the same iOS version

Answer (score -1):

Try linking the devices via Bluetooth. It might seem a *little* outlandish, but it worked for me.